# having trouble with py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to compile a python program to an executable application on Mac OS X (Catalina) using py2app, and just cannot get it to work at all, would greatly appreciate if anybody can point out what I'm doing wrong.   For the purposes of debugging my py2app problems, I have simplfied my python program down to:

```
d = 0.1
print ("starting")
for a in range (100000000):
    d = d + 0.1
print ("finishing")
```

which is meant to print "starting" to the console, run for a while (about 10s on my Mac), and then print ("finishing") and terminate.  When I run the program from the command line it works fine.  When I compile using py2app and then try to run the final compiled app, I am not getting it to do anything, no pulse, no signs of life - it just looks as if it's opening, and then nothing.  (I have similar lack of luck when I replace the print statements with file writes)

To compile my program I am using what I found on the main py2app docs:

```
rm -rf build dist
py2applet --make-setup test_py2app.py
python3 setup.py py2app -A
```

after which py2app seems to finish normally without any error messages.  As described above, though, when I double click the resulting application icon, it *seems* to open but nothing happens.

If it helps, when I open the Console window and search for all messages mentioning my app ("test_py2app") I get the following logs:

[image: screencapture of Console logs for my app, test_py2app]

(which includes the ominous sounding "Death sentinel fired!" message a few messages up from the bottom.  Note: all of this occurs with 0.2 seconds, far quicker than my app should take to run and terminate).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi--did you ever get this problem resolved? I'm experiencing it sporadically too. If so, did you have to customize your setup file at all?

Comment: Hi- sorry for the delay in replying, wasn't checking my github messages.  I found a way to do what I wanted without needed a compiled version, so no, never ended up getting py2app to work.  Sorry.